# Calling sort_values() on Pandas DataFrame raises ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, twitter, series

I have a DataFrame containing Trump's tweets. The column `polarity` contains a sentiment value for each tweet, and I am trying to sort the DataFrame `trump` based on these values by making a call to `sort_values()`.

If I write `trump.sort_values('polarity')` I get a `ValueError` saying:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

However, if I write `trump.head().sort_values('polarity')` it takes the first five rows of my DataFrame and sorts them based on their `polarity` value.

**My question is: Why can't I sort my entire table despite being able to sort the "head" of my table?**

EDIT2: (Removed unnecessary info, consolidated code/data for clarity)

```
>>> trump.head() # This is the table after adding the 'polarity' column
                     time      source         text             no_punc   polarity
786204978629185536  <time>     iPhone    <unformatted str>  <formatted>   1
786201435486781440  <time>     iPhone    <unformatted str>  <formatted>   -6.9 
786189446274248704  <time>     Android   <unformatted str>  <formatted>   1.8
786054986534969344  <time>     iPhone    <unformatted str>  <formatted>   1.5
786007502639038464  <time>     iPhone    <unformatted str>  <formatted>   1.2
```

Here is how I created the `polarity` column:

- Created DataFrame `tidy_format` w/columns `num`, `word` containing the index of a word in each tweet as well as the word itself (indexed by the id of each tweet).
- Created DataFrame `tidy` which grouped each index/word by its id number
- Created a list of each unique id from `tidy_format`
- Used nested list comprehensions to create a list with elements as the sum of each tweet's `polarity`

```
    >>> tidy_format.head()
            num  word
        786204978629185536  0   pay
        786204978629185536  1   to
        786204978629185536  2   play
        786204978629185536  3   politics
        786204978629185536  4   crookedhillary

    >>> tidy = trump['no_punc'].str.split(expand = True).stack()
    >>> tidy.head()
        786204978629185536  0               pay
                            1                to
                            2              play
                            3          politics
                            4    crookedhillary
        dtype: object

    >>> ids = list(tidy_format.index.unique())
    >>> scores = [sum([sent['polarity'][word] if word in sent['polarity'] else 0 for word in tidy[_id]]) for _id in ids]
    >>> trump['polarity'] = scores
    >>> trump['polarity'].head()
        786204978629185536      1
        786201435486781440   -6.9
        786189446274248704    1.8
        786054986534969344    1.5
        786007502639038464    1.2
        Name: polarity, dtype: object
```

Comment: can you show some example data contained in your dataframe? In theory the call to `sort_values` should be fine.

Comment: you have to find the way to say on which of the 2 columns to sort. the sort of head() is not doing anything meaningful...

Comment: Maybe try `trump.sort_values(by = 'polarity').head()['text'].iterrows()`

Comment: Not sure if this might be helpful, but take a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707658/sort-pandas-dataframe-by-column-producing-value-error

Comment: @sim Here is an example of some of the data:
`>>> trump.head()['polarity']`

`786204978629185536       1
786201435486781440    -6.9
786189446274248704     1.8
786054986534969344     1.5
786007502639038464     1.2
                      ... 
1052344365442588673    3.1
1052340597900627968   -0.1
1052270676982333442    5.2
1052268013876064256    1.4
1052268011900555265   -1.9
Name: polarity, Length: 10370, dtype: object`
Where each long number, so to speak, is an id representing a tweet and the smaller numbers represent the polarity score.

Comment: Please add that detail to your question by [edit]ing it, thanks.

Comment: @rss123 it may be more helpful to show the data that doesn't work. The data that works should be there as a reference for what is expected but there's no issue with it so from that alone it's very unlikely to find what the cause of the problem is.

Comment: @rss123: I cannot really reproduce the behaviour on my end. What type are the individual entries in the `polarity`-Series? Could it be that the compare methods on that `sort_values` internally makes use of are wrong?

Comment: @sim The type of each entry in `trump['polarity']` is `numpy.float64`. Also, @sim and @BigBen, I edited the question to include useful information/data on how I am getting my results.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. Rather than creating the `'polarity'` column manually by assigning `trump['polarity']` to the result of nested list comprehensions, I merged the `tidy_format` and `sent` DataFrames (`sent` has column `polarity` containing polarity score of every word in the VADER lexicon, indexed by each individual word) and performed operations on the resulting table:

```
>>> tidy_sent = tidy_format.merge(sent, left_on = 'word', right_index = True)
>>> tidy_sent.fillna(0, inplace = True)
>>> tidy_sent.index = tidy_sent.index.set_names('id')
>>> tidy_sent.head()
                    num word polarity
id          
786204978629185536  0   pay -0.4
783477966906925056  5   pay -0.4
771294347501461504  2   pay -0.4
771210555822477313  2   pay -0.4
764552764177481728  20  pay -0.4

>>> ts_grouped = tidy_sent.groupby('id').sum()
>>> ts_grouped.head()
                    num polarity
id      
690171403388104704  10  -2.6
690173226341691392  27  -6.0
690176882055114758  39  4.3
690180284189310976  38  -2.6
690271688127213568  18  -5.2
```

```
>>> trump['polarity'] = ts_grouped['polarity']
>>> trump.fillna(0, inplace = True)
>>> trump['polarity'].head()

786204978629185536    1.0
786201435486781440   -6.9
786189446274248704    1.8
786054986534969344    1.5
786007502639038464    1.2
Name: polarity, dtype: float64
```

Since my mistake was initially in my calculation of `trump['polarity']`, by merging tables I am able to have the correct value for this `Series`, thus allowing me to call `sort_values()` properly.

```
>>> print('Most negative tweets:')
>>> for t in trump.sort_values(by = 'polarity').head()['text']:
        print('\n  ', t)
Most negative tweets:

   the trump portrait of an unsustainable border crisis is dead on. “in the last two years, ice officers made 266,000 arrests of aliens with criminal records, including those charged or convicted of 100,000 assaults, 30,000 sex crimes &amp; 4000 violent killings.” america’s southern....

   it is outrageous that poisonous synthetic heroin fentanyl comes pouring into the u.s. postal system from china. we can, and must, end this now! the senate should pass the stop act – and firmly stop this poison from killing our children and destroying our country. no more delay!

   the rigged russian witch hunt goes on and on as the “originators and founders” of this scam continue to be fired and demoted for their corrupt and illegal activity. all credibility is gone from this terrible hoax, and much more will be lost as it proceeds. no collusion!

   ...this evil anti-semitic attack is an assault on humanity. it will take all of us working together to extract the poison of anti-semitism from our world. we must unite to conquer hate.

   james comey is a proven leaker &amp; liar. virtually everyone in washington thought he should be fired for the terrible job he did-until he was, in fact, fired. he leaked classified information, for which he should be prosecuted. he lied to congress under oath. he is a weak and.....
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a kwarg:  `trump.head().sort_values(by="polarity")` to sort the head or `trump.sort_values(by="polarity").head()` to sort everything and show the head (lowest polarity).